# How to get grub load/boot statistics?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bootloader, grub, grub2

Is it possible to know how much time grub takes to load files from `/boot` (`vmlinuz` and `initrd`) to the RAM?

As far as I know, the `boot` command loads and jumps into the kernel according to previous `linux` and `initrd` commands without any option to retrieve some stats about the processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the source code of commands in grub's repo, I found `testspeed` which gives the load stats I wanted for a given file into memory:

```
grub> testspeed /vmlinuz
File size: 3.40MiB
Elapsed time: 1.571 s
Speed: 2.16MiB/s

grub> testspeed /initrd.img
File size: 48.80MiB
Elapsed time: 8.762 s
Speed: 5.57MiB/s
```